# Quasilinear elliptic problem: Ellipticity-type conditions

Tags: reference-request, ap.analysis-of-pdes, elliptic-pde, sobolev-spaces

Consider the following quasilinear elliptic equation
$$\nabla_x (A(x,u(x),\nabla_x u(x))) + f(u,x)  = 0 $$
on a bounded domain $\Omega$, augmented with homogeneous Dirichlet boundary data: $$u|_{\partial \Omega} = 0.$$

- Where can I find references on this kinds of problems (in particular about a variational approach to solve them)?
- What's the correct formulation of a "uniform ellipticity"-type condition that gives existence and uniqueness for this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a basic result. For a detailed proof, see Theorem 5.4 in [2].

> **Theorem.** If $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ is a bounded Lipschitz domain and $$
>  F=F(x,u,\xi):\Omega\times\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R} $$ 
>   satisfies
>
> - $F$ and $\nabla_\xi F$ are continuous,
> - $\xi\mapsto F(x,u,\xi)$ is convex,
> - $F(x,u,\xi)\geq c|\xi|^p + a(x)$, $1<p<\infty$, $a\in L^1(\Omega)$,
>
> then for any $w\in W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ the functional $$ I(u)=\int_\Omega
>  F(x,u,\nabla u)\,dx $$ attains minimum in the class $$
>  W^{1,p}_w(\Omega)=\{ u\in W^{1,p}(\Omega):\, u-w\in
>  W^{1,p}_0(\Omega)\}. $$

Under some additional assumptions about $F$ this minimizer solves the elliptic equation
$$
(*)\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ div A(x,u,\nabla u)=B(x,u,\nabla u),
\quad
u-w\in W^{1,p}_0(\Omega), 
$$
where 
$$
A(x,u,\xi)=\nabla_\xi F(x,u,\xi),
\quad
B=F'_u(x,u,\xi).
$$
Thus one of the method of solving (*) is trough the associated variational problem.

Note also that convexity of $\xi\mapsto F$ implies that
$$
(**)\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \langle A(x,u,\xi)-A(x,u,\eta),\xi-\eta\rangle\geq 0
$$
which is known as the monotonicity condition so another method of solving equation (*) satisfying (**) is through the Minty-Browder theorem. The monotonicity condition is a sort of ellipticity.

For an elementary, but detailed presentation of basic variational and non-variational techniques I highly recommend:

**[1] L. C. Evans,** *Partial differential equations.* Second edition. Graduate Studies in Mathematics, 19. American Mathematical Society, Providence, RI, 2010

Anther elementary presentation is given in:

**[2] P. Hajlasz,** 
[*Non-linear elliptic partial differential equations.*](http://www.pitt.edu/~hajlasz/Notatki/Corlona%20lectures.pdf). Unpublished lecture notes.

Other books that develop material in depth are:

**[3] B. Dacorogna,** *Direct methods in the calculus of variations.* Second edition. Applied Mathematical Sciences, 78. Springer, New York, 2008.

**[4] M. Giaquinta,** *Introduction to regularity theory for nonlinear elliptic systems.* Lectures in Mathematics ETH Zürich. Birkhäuser Verlag, Basel, 1993. 
(Great book aut a lot of typos.)

**[5] M. Giaquinta, L. Martinazzi,** *An introduction to the regularity theory for elliptic systems, harmonic maps and minimal graphs*. Appunti. Scuola Normale Superiore di Pisa (Nuova Serie) [Lecture Notes. Scuola Normale Superiore di Pisa (New Series)], 2. Edizioni della Normale, Pisa, 2005.

**[6] E. Giusti,** *Direct Methods in the Calculus of Variations.*
 World Scientific Publishing Co., Inc., River Edge, NJ, 2003.

Comment: Thank you. And what is the role of that growth condition? (third bullet point)

Comment: @Dal The growth condition guarantees existence of minimizers in $W^{1,p}$. Later I will add more references. The statements are quite technical and there is no way I can carefully state all relevant results. Just use the above result as a guideline and search the books. I need to be in my office to check other books so you need to wait a few days for more references.

Comment: Thank you. I look forward to it.

Comment: Thank you for the update. In the model problem you mentioned, why are there no assumptions on the growth of $F$ with respect to the $u$ variable?